# Md5 password problems

Tags: php, mysql, passwords, md5

This is my problem: I have a table call users in my database, the column password works with md5, but when I save strings , for example: `benjalucas(de643ebda0285edc22145bbd95c345e5)`, `pepe3421` and other similars
I can not logged in my application with those passwords.

The password column   estructure is :

```
type - varchar(32)
latin1_swedish_ci
```

Regards!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Hashing password using `md5` indeed is a problem. Please stop and start using proper hashes: http://us2.php.net/password

Comment: Word of advice. Do **NOT** store passwords using MD5.

Comment: please be more specific and give us some codes to understand the matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined the the length of character in your columns that is 32 and you password string is characters are more than 32 **benjalucas(de643ebda0285edc22145bbd95c345e5),** are 44 characters, this complete string is of **54 characters**

> benjalucas(de643ebda0285edc22145bbd95c345e5), pepe3421

Try increasing the length of you field